# How do I avoid linebreak between caption and description of figure?

Tags: formatting, captions, line-breaking

My caption looks like this:
**Fig. 1.1 | A picture of a boat (caption):**
This boat has a blue sail and is made of wood (description).

But I want:
**Fig. 1.1 | A picture of a boat (caption):** This boat has a blue sail and is made of wood (description).

This is my code:

```
\usepackage[labelsep=pipe,font=small,labelfont={sf,bf},justification=RaggedRight]{caption}
\newcommand{\img}[4]{
\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=#2\linewidth]{#1}
  \caption{\textsf{\textbf{#3:}}}\nolinebreak[4]#4
\label{img:#1}
\end{figure}
}

\img{file.jpg}{0.5}{A picture of a boat (caption):}{This boat has a blue sail and is made of wood (description).}
```

Thank you very much! (This is my first post, I hope it's allright)

## SOLUTION

Credit to [Torbjørn T.](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/586/torbj%C3%B8rn-t). \caption has the ability to display what ends up in the List of Figures, i.e. \caption[LoF entry]{my caption text}. Important: To get the results one needs to compile twice.
Thus my new code is:

```
\usepackage[labelsep=pipe,font=small,labelfont={sf,bf},justification=RaggedRight]{caption}
\newcommand{\img}[4]{
\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=#2\linewidth]{#1}
  \caption[#3]{\textsf{\textbf{#3: }} #4}
\label{img:#1}
\end{figure}
}

\img{file.jpg}{0.5}{A picture of a boat (caption):}{This boat has a blue sail and is made of wood (description).}
```

Comment: Welcome! Can't you just put `#4` inside the caption?

Comment: No, because then all of the text gets listed in "List of Figures".

Comment: Ah, didn't think of that. `\caption` has an optional argument to specify what goes into the LoF, e.g. `\caption[#3]{\textsf{\textbf{#3:}} #4}`.

Comment: Oh, you are right. Actually I checked that but you need to compile twice to get the result. I did it just once and thought it's not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a key-value implementation of your setup, allowing a little more flexibility if you wish to change your mind in the future:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{caption,ragged2e}

\DeclareCaptionLabelSeparator{pipe}{ $\vert$ }
\captionsetup{
  labelsep=pipe,
  font={small,sf,bf},
  justification=RaggedRight
}

\usepackage{xkeyval,float,graphicx}

\makeatletter
\define@cmdkey{myimages}[img@]{file}{}
\define@cmdkeys{myimages}[img@]{width,caption,description,label}[\relax]{}

\newcommand{\insertimage}[1]{%
  \begin{figure}[H]
    \setkeys{myimages}{file={}, width, caption, description, label,#1}
    \centering
    \expandafter\ifx\img@width\relax
      \includegraphics{\img@file}%
    \else
      \includegraphics[width=\img@width]{\img@file}%
    \fi
    \expandafter\ifx\img@caption\relax\else
      \caption[\img@caption]{\img@caption \expandafter\ifx\img@description\relax.\else~(caption): {\normalfont \img@description~(description).}\fi}
      \expandafter\ifx\img@label\relax\else
        \label{\img@label}%
      \fi
    \fi
  \end{figure}
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\listoffigures

\insertimage{
  file=example-image,
  width=0.3\linewidth,
  caption={A picture of a boat},
  description={This boat has a blue sail and is made of wood},
  label=img:boat
}

\insertimage{
  file=example-image-a,
  width=100pt,
  caption={A picture of a fish}
}

\insertimage{
  file=example-image-b,
  width=.25\linewidth,
  description={A picture of a whale}
}

\end{document}
```

It is assumed that if you don't supply a `caption`, there no need to supply a `description` (and even if you do, it won't be set). Similarly for `label`. Also, the suffixes `(caption)` and `(description)` is added automatically, and not inserted into the LoF.

Fundamentally, both the `caption` and the `description` is put into the `\caption`, just with different font formatting.

Comment: This is very good! It's not the easiest to understand, but it solves my problem and is flexible. Thank you very much!